# Pytorch lightning fit in a loop

Tags: python, pytorch, time-series, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-forecasting

I'm training a time series N-HiTS model (pyrorch forecasting) and need to implement a cross validation on time series my data for training, which requires changing training and validation datasets every n epochs. I cannot fit all my data at once because I need to preserve the temporal order in my training data. I have created my train/val data splits and respective dataloaders from them, which I keep in 2 separate arrays. I need to replace my training and validation data every n epochs in trainer.fit to replace them with the next split.

[Time series moving windows CV for illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIUqY.png)

I've tried to put my trainer.fit into a loop and increase the max_epochs parameter every n epochs (trainer.fit_loop.max_epochs together with trainer.fit_loop.epoch_loop.max_steps), which didn't seem to change anything.

```
val_dataloaders = []

for s in splits:
  training = TimeSeriesDataSet(
      s[lambda x: x.batch_hours_from_start <= training_cutoff],
      time_idx="batch_hours_from_start",
      #other params
  )


  validation = TimeSeriesDataSet.from_dataset(training, s, predict=True, stop_randomization=True)

  # create dataloaders for  our model
  train_dataloaders.append(training.to_dataloader(train=True, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=2))
  val_dataloaders.append(validation.to_dataloader(train=False, batch_size=batch_size * 10, num_workers=2))
  
trainer = pl.Trainer(
    max_epochs=10,
    reload_dataloaders_every_n_epochs=5
)


nhits = NHiTS.from_dataset(
    training, 
    learning_rate=1e-3, 
    loss=RMSE(),
    prediction_length=8,
)

trainer.fit(
    nhits,
    train_dataloaders=train_dataloaders,
    val_dataloaders=val_dataloaders,
)
```

I have found the reload_dataloaders_every_n_epochs parameter in the pl trainer. From the documentation trainer.fit train_dataloaders parameter takes an iterable, but I'm getting validation_step() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given error message every time I call it .

Is there any way to reload the data every n epochs that I can use in my use case?